# How can I project earth centered cartesian coordinates (EPSG:4978) to lat lon within Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, epsg, ecef

I have a PostGIS database with `X`, `Y`, and `Z` ECEF coordinates and I want to create a layer in Geoserver that displays these coordinates as points in OpenLayers. In Geoserver's create layer page there is a Coordinate Reference System heading with fields Native SRS, Declared SRS, and SRS Handling. I think I want `Native SRS` to be `EPSG:4978`, Declared SRS to be EPSG:4326, and SRS Handling to be `reproject native to declared` but I cannot edit the Native SRS field! Am I trying to do something unsupported?

Comment: yes, that isn't how that works - set declared to 4978 and let GeoServer handle the rest. I've no idea if it will actually support 4978 though

Comment: Then why is there a field for Native SRS?

Comment: So that well formed srs can appear there. Some times data lies so geoserver allows you to change it.

Comment: But Geoserver *doesn't* allow you to change it. It's not an editable field.

Comment: Exactly it is an intrinsic part of the data so you can not change it, just override it if it is wrong or undefined

Comment: So if I supply my Geometry with a bogus SRS code I should be able to edit the Native SRS field? I'm pretty sure that doesn't happen but I'll try it.

Comment: No, you can *declare* the correct one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60846/discussion-between-medley56-and-iant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. It's very unusual to work with cartesian coordinates in GIS, aside from if you're doing geodesy work.

You will need to convert these X, Y, Z coordinates to Lat, Lon (height) before importing into PostGIS.

Comment: Ok, so Geoserver only supports a few EPSG codes and 4978 isn't one of them?

Comment: Hi @medley56, I think you'll find that GeoServer supports nearly all EPSG codes, but not cartesian ones. It's really only supports 2D CRSs, I think.

Comment: Geoserver supports only 2D CRS but you can get it to recognize other EPSG codes from your geometry objects when mapping to XML schemas. e.g. GeodesyML.